# Make modal available to every view in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have created a Middleware function that uses View::share to pass foo to any other view. So, I know I can go into a view and foo is available to me there.
My need is kind of odd, yet I am sure there is a way to accomplish it. I need to pass foo to a modal and then, without using an include on the view, have that modal show on every page. Once a user acknowledges the modal, a flag will be set in the db and foo is set to null so the modal wouldn't show.
So, my question is, without including the partial in every view, is there a way to show the modal on every page until the flag is set?

Comment: Could view composer work for you?

Comment: Easy. Include it in the master page conditionally. If you need a controller, type out the whole namespace to reach that controller. Or create a helper function for your need if the condition is met.

Comment: @Avi, that is a thought. I don't use view composer very often and so didn't think about it... But am looking at that possibility right now.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey, Not sure if I am following you, but I think I am or at least you gave me an idea. Include it in the layout file and then render only if the condition is met. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @Premisoft yes :) The layout file, for some reason I use to call it the master page. That's the one. After the main section. If your Bootstrap Javascript include is in the header. If not, you'll have to include it after Bootstrap. Just above the closing html tag will do. For a modal that doesn't really matter. My layout has 3 conditions on it. It renders without an issue, contradiction nor delay. The beauty is the simplicity if you want to get rid of it somewhere in the future.

Comment: That works perfectly! Make that an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Premisoft done, thanks. Sorry for the late answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in the layout file. Somewhere below you import the Bootstrap JavaScript. If Bootstrap is imported in the header, it's best to import it under the main section of the layout file.

As this is a modal, you could import it right above the `</html>` closing tag.

If you like a condition going along with partial view, it will look something like this:

```
@if ($condition == true)
  @include('path.to.modal')
@endif
```

The beauty is that you have to include it only once. Just make sure the condition is generally accessible/existing. This is usually done through MiddleWare. If, for some reason, the condition changes or is no more needed, there are only 3 lines of code to adapt/delete.